# Alert User Every 24 Hours To Update Data On App Start Up

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, uilocalnotification

One of my apps uses a database that synch's online with another. The online data update pretty frequently, so I'd like to remind users to update their local data every 24 hours after they open the app, not while it's closed.

Is it easier to do this with NSUserDefaults, or is it possible to schedule a Local Notification to execute only if the application is opened?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults.

Notifications are specifically designed to work while the app is not running :)

When the app is started, check the time of the last update and then start an NSTimer to fire at the correct time and tell the user to update.

However, is this good ui practice?

Surely it's better for your app to update itself in the background without interrupting the user?

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I'm looking for.  I do update data in the background as it happens, but it was a requirement from someone else to ask/remind users to update the data.